# What is difference between !false and != false

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, boolean-logic

I don't get why while loop works, done is declared as false and while loop condition is to run when done isn't false. So why does it gets executed? 
Also is there difference between !done and done != false ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListDemo
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> toDoList = new ArrayList<String>(20);
        System.out.println("Enter list entries, when prompted.");
        boolean done = false;
        String next = null;
        String answer;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(!done)
        {
            System.out.println("Input an  entry:");
            next = keyboard.nextLine();
            toDoList.add(next);
            System.out.println("More items for the list? ");
            answer = keyboard.nextLine();
            if(!(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")))
            {
                done = true;
            }
            System.out.println("The list contains:");
            for(String entry: toDoList)
            {
                System.out.println(entry);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `done == false` - `!done == !false == true` - Thus the loop runs. Where's the confusion?

Comment: done is false and while loop should loop only when done equals true, do why does it loops?

Answer (score 1):

`!` ([exclamation mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark), sometimes "bang") is the [logical negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) of a `boolean`, when you say `while(!done)` it is the **same** as `while(done != true)` **and** `while(done == false)`; but it's *shorter*.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `done` is of type `boolean`. So this `!done` is the negation of `done`. Hence, if `done` is true, `!done` is false. While, if `done` is false, `!done` is true.

That being said is different the appliance of negation operator, `!`, from checking if a boolean value is different from false, true.

Comment: so whlie(!done) means do this task while (!done) is true?

Comment: @peace9000 exactly ! You can read it as while not done do the following...So now you see the expressiveness of this statement.

Comment: When `done` is false, `!done` is true. So it will be executed at least once. When this `!(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))` becomes true, the done's value would be true and this would be the last while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
!
```

is a unary operator. Works with one boolean.

```
!=
```

is a binary operator. You have to compare two boolean expressions/variables with it.

---

a `while` loop runs until the boolean expression inside it becomes false.

Your `!done` expression means "not done" so your loop's logic is the following :

Until it is not done, keep looping. Which is pure logic.